# How to add title bottom border with html css

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to add a title border with CSS. but I can't find the actual result.

[image: screenshot]

```css
.widget-title {
  font-size: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 30;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  text-decoration-thickness: 0.1875rem;
  text-decoration-color: green;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="widget-title"> Widget title </h1>
```

Comment: your code works and you already added border to your headline, what is exactly your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gray line, you have to use `::before` element, hope its works

```css
.widget-title {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    width: 33.33%
}
.widget-title span{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.widget-title:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 2px;
}
.widget-title span:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}



.d-flex{
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
<h1 class="widget-title"> <span>Widget title</span></h1>
<h1 class="widget-title"> <span>Title sm</span></h1>
<h1 class="widget-title"> <span>Widget title long</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tXtCPFK0XzTi

There has a border-radius too.

Comment: @KhondokarShamimAhmed I have updated the code please check

Answer (score -1):

```
.widget-title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0 0 5px; 
}
```

Steps:
1)Add border-bottom.
2)Change the padding-bottom.

This will work. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).